# CSS Custom Button Colors

Tags: html, css, django, button

I'm trying to change the color of this specific button to blue (the facebook button which is called btn btn-primary mb-2), however, I'm unable to access its class file. Here is the HTML code and button CSS

```
<div class ="login">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="login-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <p class="forgot-password"><a class= "fgt-password" href="">Forgot Password</a></p>
            <button class="login-btn">Login</button>
            <h7>--------------------------------- OR ---------------------------------</h7>
            <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
                <a href="{% url 'rango:facebook_login' %}">Login with Facebook</a>
            </button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS code

```
.form button {
font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
outline: 0;
background: #006600;
width: 100%;
border: 0;
padding: 15px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 14px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
transition: all 0.3 ease;
cursor: pointer;
```

}

I tried .btn-primary or .form btn-primary but none work. Any ideas how I can access the class through CSS?

Comment: facebook login button color is ```#156FE5``` try this

Comment: are you using bootstrap here and do you want to target only the facebook login button ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with `css`, not with `djngog`??

i notice you are tryng to override some property that exist in `btn btn-primary` so try to add `!important` in the end of each common property to emphasize your overriden property

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will help you**

```css
.form button {
font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
outline: 0;
background: #156FE5;
width: 100%;
border: 0;
padding: 15px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 14px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
transition: all 0.3 ease;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class ="login">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="login-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <p class="forgot-password"><a class= "fgt-password" href="">Forgot Password</a></p>
            <button class="login-btn">Login</button>
            <h7>--------------------------------- OR ---------------------------------</h7>
            <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
                <a href="{% url 'rango:facebook_login' %}">Login with Facebook</a>
            </button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```